# How to prove this inequality $|y|\leq \left(\dfrac{\tan{r}}{r}\right)|u|$ to be true?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Given $y=\tan{u}$ with $|u|\leq r< \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. How can we show that $|y|\leq \left(\dfrac{\tan{r}}{r}\right)|u|$?

My initial attempts was: $y=\tan{u}\implies|y|\leq |\tan{u}|=\dfrac{|u||\tan{u}|}{|\tan{u}|}=\dfrac{|u|\tan{|u|}}{|\tan{u}|}\leq \dfrac{|u|\tan{r}}{|\tan{u}|}$.

But I am finding it hard to proceed from here on. If anyone of you kindly sees this and post a response to guide me towards the proof, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the symmetry of the tangent suffices it to show that
$$
\frac{\tan(u)}{u} \le \frac{\tan(r)}{r}
$$
for $0 < u \le r < \pi/2$, i.e. that $f(x) = \tan(x)/x$ is *increasing* on the interval $(0, \pi/2)$.

That is true because then tangent is *convex* on $[0, \pi/2)$, but one can also compute the derivative and verify that it is non-negative:
$$
 f'(x) = \frac{(1+ \tan^2(x))x - \tan(x)}{x^2} = \frac{x-\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x^2 \cos^2(x)} = \frac{x-\frac 12 \sin(2x)}{x^2 \cos^2(x)} \ge  0 \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

first we solve for $0<u\leq r < \frac{\pi}{2}$:
$$\tan u \leq \frac{\tan r}{r}u \Rightarrow r\tan u \leq u\tan r \Rightarrow \frac{\tan u}{\tan r} \leq \frac{u}{r}$$
since $\tan x = x + O(x^3)$
so :
$$\frac{u+O(x^3)}{r+O(r^3)} - \frac{u}{r} \leq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{rO(u^3)-uO(r^3)}{r^2+rO(r^3)}$$
since $u<r$ the said fraction is negative and we have solved the question for the first half of question.the other can also be proven simillarly.